# How do I download a JPG file from the server?

Tags: 8, forms

I have written a custom module in which i have a download button like given below.

```
$form['topics_info_graph']['download_graph'] = array(
 '#type'  => 'button',
 '#value' =>  t('Download Graph'),
 '#button_type' => 'button',
 '#ajax' => array(
   'callback' => 'digitaliq_bckgrd_variable_ajax_download_callback', 
   'wrapper' => 'download_graph',
   'event' => 'click',
 ),
);
```

Onclick of this button i need to download a jpg image which is located in the temp folder.
I'm able identify the file name and the path, Not sure how to download. any help?

```
function digitaliq_bcgrd_variable_file_download($filename) {
  $temporary_directory = variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path().'/files').'/tmp';
  $temp_path = $temporary_directory . '/';
  // Download logic should come here, any help?
}
```

Comment: Have you tried digging into how symfony does it yet? IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010411/symfony2-force-file-download

Answer (score 0):

You can set the response headers from the PHP code to trigger a browser download of the file, e.g, something like:

```
function digitaliq_bcgrd_variable_file_download($filename) {
  $tmp = variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path().'/files').'/tmp';
  $filepath = $tmp . '/'. $filename;
  if ($data = file_get_contents($filepath)) {
    $file = new stdClass();
    $file->contents = $data;
    $file->filename = $filename;
    return EXAMPLE_serve_download($file);
  }
  drupal_not_found();
}


/**
 * Serve a file for download
 * @param $file
 * An object keyed with filename and contents
 */
function EXAMPLE_serve_download($file, $type = 'application/octet-stream') {

  if (empty($file->contents)) {
    drupal_not_found();
  }

  $headers = array(
    'Content-Type'              => $type,
    'Content-Disposition'       => 'attachment; filename="' . $file->filename . '"',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
    'Pragma'                    => 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control'             => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
    'Expires'                   => '0',
    'Accept-Ranges'             => 'bytes'
  );
  if (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
  }
  foreach ($headers as $name => $value) {
    drupal_add_http_header($name, $value);
  }

  drupal_send_headers();
  print $file->contents;
  drupal_exit();

}
```

Comment: Does it work for an AJAX call? Notice that the OP is using the "wrapper" property, and what returned from the AJAX callback replaces what is present in the wrapper.

Comment: The above solution doesnt work in ajax call, any further help?

Comment: Ah ok, perhaps you could use a direct link to the file instead of the ajax callback? e.g hook menu with filename parameter or similar. With the same handler, it should serve the file for download.

Comment: You can't do this in AJAX, the simplest solution will be for the button to be an ordinary link which points to the download callback as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the server using the FTP protocol, and download the file to show it.

```
function example_download_image() {
  $local_file = 'tmp/download.jpg';
  $server_file = 'tmp_server/download.jpg';
  $ftp_server = "ftp.server.com";
  $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
  $ftp_user_name = "user_name";
  $ftp_user_pass = "password";
  $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
  ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
  if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    // Show the file.
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message("There was a problem\n");
  }
  ftp_close($conn_id);
}
```