# Download an image through an AJAX call

Tags: forms, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to download JPG file from the server](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54655/how-to-download-jpg-file-from-the-server)

I have written a custom module in which i have a download button like given below.

```
$form['topics_info_graph']['download_graph'] = array(
 '#type'  => 'button',
 '#value' =>  t('Download Graph'),
 '#button_type' => 'button',
 '#ajax' => array(
   'callback' => 'digitaliq_bckgrd_variable_ajax_download_callback', 
   'wrapper' => 'download_graph',
   'event' => 'click',
 ),
);
```

Onclick of this button i need to download a jpg image which is located in the temp folder.
I'm able identify the file name and the path, I need to download the file using Ajax Call. Any help?

```
function digitaliq_bcgrd_variable_file_download($filename) {
  $temporary_directory = variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path().'/files').'/tmp';
  $temp_path = $temporary_directory . '/';
  // Download logic should come here, any help?
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same question you asked 2 hours ago.

Comment: And it has nothing to do with Drupal...search for "ajax image download" on Google